# How to use jquery dynatree plugin as accordion menu?

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I am using [dynatree](https://code.google.com/p/dynatree/) as a tree menu in my project. When the user expand a node i want the previous expanded node to collapse (like an accordion menu).

I think that i have to collapse it in the `onExpand` event of dynatree. But i dont know how.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your tree definition:

```
autoCollapse: true,
```

From the [documentation](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html#h4.1):  Automatically collapse all siblings, when a node is expanded.